# Is there a way to clear an input type="number" like when using type="search"

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a `Bootstrap 4` `form` with various `inputs` on some number, some text and others email.

I have already sorted my text `inputs` by adding the below, which is displaying the 'x' in the `input`

```
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance: searchfield-cancel-button;
}
```

But I want the same for my 'number' and 'email' `input`s

I tried using the below to see if it works, but it doesn't

```
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance: searchfield-cancel-button;
}
```

I have also used the below `CSS` to remove the arrows when using `type='number'` and again it works fine

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Thought I'd ask before I revert to using `regex` for my number `inputs`

[image]

**HTML**

```
<input id="one" class="form-control" type="search" value="Test company name" />
<input id="two" class="form-control" type="number" value="123456" />
<input id="two" class="form-control" type="number" value="12345634" />
```

As you can see the arrows are not displaying for my number `input`s which is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

There is good and bad news. The bad news first: the webkit cancel button is only available to input fields of type `search`.

The good news: you can create the button yourself.

Copy and paste the following CSS:

```
.close-button {
  color: #1e52e3;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: monospace,sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
}

.close-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

and change the font-size to what is suitable by trial and error.

Then add this Javascript before the `</body>` tag in the relevant HTML:

```
<script>
var fields = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=number],input[type=email]');

fields.forEach(function(input) {
  let x = document.createElement('span');
  x.classList.add('close-button');
  x.innerHTML = 'x';
  x.style.left = input.clientWidth - 15;
  x.onmousedown = removeContent;
  input.parentNode.insertBefore(x, input);
  input.oninput = toggleCloseButton;
  input.addEventListener( 'focusin', toggleCloseButton);
  input.addEventListener( 'focusout', hideCloseButton);
});

function toggleCloseButton() {
   if (this.value.length > 0) {
     this.previousSibling.style.display = 'block';
   } else {
     this.previousSibling.style.display = 'none';
   }
}

function hideCloseButton() {
  this.previousSibling.style.display = 'none';
}

function removeContent(){
  this.nextSibling.value = '';
  this.nextSibling.focus();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking this wouldn't be allowed. I'll probably just go with the number `regex` and change the `input` to a `type="search"`